# Efficient way to connect the k nearest neighbors in a scatterplot using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to construct a nearest neighbor plot, i.e. a scatterplot in which each datapoint is connected to its k nearest neighbors. My current solution works but is obviously not very efficient. Here is what I got so far:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

X = np.random.random(500).reshape((250, 2))
k = 4

# matrix of pairwise Euclidean distances
distmat = squareform(pdist(X, 'euclidean'))

# select the kNN for each datapoint
neighbors = np.sort(np.argsort(distmat, axis=1)[:, 0:k])

plt.figure(figsize = (8, 8))
plt.scatter(X[:,0], X[:,1], c = 'black')
for i in np.arange(250):
    for j in np.arange(k):
        x1 = np.array([X[i,:][0], X[neighbors[i, j], :][0]])
        x2 = np.array([X[i,:][1], X[neighbors[i, j], :][1]])
        plt.plot(x1, x2, color = 'black')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Is there a more efficient way to construct this plot?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a LineCollection to plot all edges in one go, instead of plotting them each individually:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection

N = 250
X = np.random.rand(250,2)
k = 4

# matrix of pairwise Euclidean distances
distmat = squareform(pdist(X, 'euclidean'))

# select the kNN for each datapoint
neighbors = np.sort(np.argsort(distmat, axis=1)[:, 0:k])

# get edge coordinates
coordinates = np.zeros((N, k, 2, 2))
for i in np.arange(250):
    for j in np.arange(k):
        coordinates[i, j, :, 0] = np.array([X[i,:][0], X[neighbors[i, j], :][0]])
        coordinates[i, j, :, 1] = np.array([X[i,:][1], X[neighbors[i, j], :][1]])

# create line artists
lines = LineCollection(coordinates.reshape((N*k, 2, 2)), color='black')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize = (8, 8))
ax.scatter(X[:,0], X[:,1], c = 'black')
ax.add_artist(lines)
plt.show()
```

On my machine, your code takes about 1 sec for me to run; my version needs 65 ms.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was looking for!

Comment: how do you choose the maximum distance to be considered nearest neighbours? And can you do the same with 3D and eventually just plot a 2D?

Comment: Typically, there is no distance cutoff with k-nearest neighbours. The k closest points are chosen, even if any of them are far away. And yes, k-nearest neighbours generalises to arbitrary dimensions. I can't comment on the plotting as this really depends what you want to depict.